# Randomly merge value of same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of names and their genders like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| id         | name     | gender|
+------------+----------+-------+
|         1  | James    |     M |
|         2  | Tom      |     M |
|         3  | Bill     |     M |
|         4  | Philip   |     M |
|         5  | Steve    |     M |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

And I want this result:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|     id     | name               |
+------------+--------------------+
|         1  | James Steve        |
|         2  | Tom Philip         |
|         3  | Steve James        |
|         4  | Bill Tom           |
|         5  | Steve Tom          |
+------------+--------------------+
```

It should pick any random name from the column and merge it with another value from same column.

Explanation by author from the comments:

I want to concatenate any random name from the column with other random name from same column and generate a new name by combination of both values.

I never merged two values from same column together

Comment: What is the question you're asking? Where is the problem?

Comment: What does gender have to do with this?

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your logic for combining names from random rows???

Comment: I want to concatenate any random name from the column with other random name from same column and generate a new name by combination of both values. I never merged two values from same column together.

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @FahadAwan the name can repeat? For example, "James James Steve"

Comment: Umm no it should be like James Steve but not james james steve.

Comment: The question already has expected values. so Ive removed those edited in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird thing to do in SQL, but here you go:

```
--some example data
declare @X table(name varchar(10))
insert into @X values ('Jim'), ('Tom'), ('Jerry'), ('Mickey')

;with cte as (
select row_number() over (order by ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))) [random_rn],
       row_number() over (order by name) [rn],
       name
from @X)

select c1.name + ' ' + c2.name from cte c1 join cte c2 on c1.rn = c2.random_rn
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f44d0/1)

You can use something like this :

```
select id, name + ' ' + 
    (select top 1 name from Table1 where name<>t1.name ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Name 
from Table1 t1
```

In the above query `NEWID()` generates a GUID for each row and because GUIDs are pretty random, the ordering means you get the records in random order and using `top 1` it is picking the first one. So in the above query, it will pick a name randomly other than the current one and merge it with the current name.

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).